# Dynamcillay create imageview and onTouchEvent

Tags: android, dynamic, position, imageview, touch

I want to dynamically add the imageview and apply ontouch event to them.I got that multiple images add from album to my layout dynamically.But when I am trying to get each imagview position it always shown the last one I placed rather than respective imageview position.

This is the code I tried,

```
    image = new ImageView(this);
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                          Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                          image.setImageBitmap(bit);
                          ;

                            scrool.addView(image);
                            image.getLayoutParams().height =  400;
                            image.getLayoutParams().width =  300;
                           System.out.println( "Data Recieved! " + filePath);
                           int[] values = new int[2]; 
                            image.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                            System.out.println("x location::"+values[0]);
                            System.out.println(" y location::"+values[1]);


                           image.setOnTouchListener(this);

                            }
                          }
```

And my touch event is,

```
      @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("in  touch");
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params  = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                System.out.println("in move touch");
                int[] values = new int[2]; 
                image.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                System.out.println("x location  ::"+values[0]);
                System.out.println(" y location  ::"+values[1]);
                 int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                    if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                        x_cord = windowwidth;
                    }
                    if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                        y_cord = windowheight;
                    }
                    params.leftMargin = x_cord;
                    params.topMargin = y_cord;
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;

            }

          //notelayout.invalidate();
           scrool.invalidate();
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: ur image object of a class level variable so the reference changes every-time u create a new image object,modifying the image reference, So obviously it will have the new reference i.e the last one

Comment: Thanks for your comment.How can I change the reference becoz I am addng the imageview dynamically.

Comment: Instead of making it a class level variable use `final ImageView img=new ImageView(this)` and the proceed with the answer given by @Eldar Mensutov. That should work.

Comment: so far I assigned ontouch to imageview,so for what view I will assign ontouch,If i get the imageview inside the ontouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, cause each time when you called `image = new ImageView(this);`  you override reference.
As solution I am recommending you next code:

```
 @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          ImageView imageView = (ImaveView)v;
          //do something with imageView;
```

Comment: so where do I assign the ontouch?

Comment: micky, at same place.

Comment: Mensultov I get the relativelayout in my ontouch event.Can u see my edited question

Comment: Yes, do all the same but add the code from my answer and instead  `image` object use 'imageView' in `onTouch` method

Comment: It works thanks but when I plpacing second image It hides the first one

Comment: That is another problem

Comment: Can u tell me why I am facing that?

Comment: Let's try, what you want to achieve?

Comment: As you said I got the solution.But When I am dynamically adding the imageviews the old one get overlapped by the new one.

Comment: Maybe because you are using RelativeLayout as parent  and for each ImageView you apply same LayoutParams? Just for test Replace Relative to Linear.

Comment: I want to insert all my dynamically created imageviews into sqlite database.I don't know how to insert.Because imageviews are dynamically created I want to get their position and place it where they occupied.I want an idea?

Comment: I can only suggest you don't do it.